# How to create a keyboard from tkinter buttons that stores the entered letter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am writing a python hangman code with tkinter interactive window, which includes a keyboard. I have created the keyboard, however I cannot figure out how to find out which keyboard key was pressed by the user and how to store it as a letter in a variable. I will be really grateful for any help!

```
klavesnice = Tk()
klavesnice.geometry("800x700+120+100")
buttons = []  
buttons = [
        'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
        'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
        'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'
    ]

radek=3 #row
sloupec=0 #column

for button in buttons:
    command=lambda  x=button: select(x)
    if button!='Space':
        Button(klavesnice,text=button,width=5,font=("arial",14,"bold"),bg='powder blue',command=command,padx=3.5,pady=3.5,bd=5).grid(row=radek,column=sloupec)
    if button=='Space':
        Button(klavesnice,text=button,command=command).grid(row=5,column=sloupec)
    sloupec+=1
    #určení rozložení klávesnice
    if sloupec>9 and radek==3:
        sloupec=0
        radek+=1
    if sloupec>8 and radek==4:
        sloupec=0
        radek+=1
```

The code above is what displays the keyboard and the code below is the only thing I was able to come up with, which does not save the clicked key to a variable.

```
zadane=""
entry=Text(zadane_rm,width=43,height=3)
entry.grid(row=1,columnspan=40)
def select(value):
    if value=='Space':
        entry.insert(END,'')
    else:
        entry.insert(END, value)
```

I would like to store the clicked letter in a string variable called `zadane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want only requires modifying the `select()` function so it appends the current `value` argument to the global `zadane` string variable. Note I have reformatted your code to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines more closely to make it more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk  # Avoid `import *`

klavesnice = tk.Tk()
klavesnice.geometry("800x700+120+100")

buttons = [
    'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
    'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
    'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'
]

zadane = ''
entry = tk.Text(klavesnice, width=43, height=3)
entry.grid(row=1, columnspan=40)

def select(value):
    global zadane
    if value == 'Space':
        entry.insert('end', ' ')
    else:
        entry.insert('end', value)
        zadane = zadane + value
        print(f'{zadane=!r}')


radek = 3 #row
sloupec = 0 #column

for button in buttons:
    command = lambda x=button: select(x)
    if button != 'Space':
        tk.Button(klavesnice, text=button, width=5, font=("arial", 14, "bold"),
                  bg='powder blue', command=command, padx=3.5, pady=3.5, bd=5
                 ).grid(row=radek, column=sloupec)
    if button == 'Space':
        tk.Button(klavesnice, text=button, command=command).grid(row=5, column=sloupec)
    sloupec += 1
    # Specify the keyboard layout
    if sloupec > 9 and radek == 3:
        sloupec = 0
        radek += 1
    if sloupec > 8 and radek == 4:
        sloupec = 0
        radek += 1

klavesnice.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way to only store a single entered letter, (that would change everytime a key is pressed) not a whole string of them?

Comment: Yes, just change the `zadane = zadane + value` in the `select()` function to `zadane = value` and it will only ever contain the last letter clicked.